# Whatever happened to Jenny Tyler?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-last-supper

The 1995 film *[The Last Supper](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113613/)* begins with a missing person's poster showing a young girl named Jenny Tyler. This reappears multiple times in the movie but from what I've seen her fate is never revealed (a character is a suspect in her disappearance yet whether he did anything to her is not confirmed)- does anyone know what Jenny Tyler's fate was?

Comment: There are 4 movies that I can find all with the exact same name....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not revealed in the movie.

We can only suspect it might have been Zack (the group's first victim and the suspect in Jenny's case) that kidnapped or killed her, but there is no clear indication in the film that it was really him.

Jenny Tyler is basically a plot the device to introduce the sheriff character and allow the sheriff finding the group, so her fate can be left unexplained.